# Bernoulli scheme

Tags: probability

Cable link has $k$ channels that connect two cities where $n$ subscribers.
Each subscriber uses telephone in average $l$ min/hour.

Find probability that there will be trouble-free service subscribers.
$n = 1000, k = 130, l =6$

I do not understand what is the experiment in that case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any given time the probability than a subscriber is on line is $p=l/60$. We model the number trying to use the line as a random variable $\sim \mbox{Binomial}(n,p)$.

There will be congestion if the number attempting to use the line at any time is greater than the number of channels. The probability of this is:
$$
p_{\mbox{congestion}}=1-B(k,n,p)
$$
where $B(k,n,p)$ is the cumulative distribution for the binomial distribution, that is it is the probability that the RV $\sim \mbox{Binomial}(n,p)$ takes a value $\le k$.

So it remains to plug in the values $k=130$, $n=1000$ and $p=6/60=0.1$

Comment: What formula can you suggest for calc B(k,n,p)? I tried [link](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx) and got 0.0003719...
$1-0.0003719 = 0.9996281$ But in book ans is 0.9993

Comment: First choice would be to use a binomial calculator like [this one](http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx). Second choice would be to use the normal approximation to the binomial $N(np, np(1-p))$ (plus a continuity correction)